# rsyslog failed to start because of kamailio process

Tags: logging, rsyslog, kamailio

```
service rsyslog start
```

> ```
> Starting system logger: Can't open or create /var/run/syslogd.pid.
> Can't write pid.
> ```

I am using kamailio with rsyslog. When I kill kamailio, rsyslog gets locked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format it - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit to provide any additional details in order to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to use sudo to execute that command or become root -- the error message is about insufficient privileges to create a file on the system.